# Arithmetic compound operator overload as non-member

Tags: c++, class, templates, operator-overloading

I've written a templated class that implements some basic operator overloading, following the guidelines provided by [this particularly insightful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421706/what-are-the-basic-rules-and-idioms-for-operator-overloading):

```
template <typename _type>
class myClass {
    // ...
    template<_input_type> myClass<_type>& operator+=(const myClass<_input_type>& _other);
    // ...
}
```

with the arithmetic compound operators written as members:

```
template <typename _type>
template <typename _input_type>
myClass<_type>& myClass<_type>::operator+=(const myClass<_input_type>& _other) { 
    static_assert(std::is_arithmetic<_type>::value);
    // do stuff
    return *this;
};
```

and the non-compound operator as a non-member:

```
template <typename _type, typename _input_type> 
inline myClass<_type> operator+(myClass<_type>& _o1, myClass<_input_type> _o2) { 
    return _o1+=_o2;
};
```

However, due to the template `myClass` can be used for several data types, some of them non-numeric that can't handle `+`,`-`,`*` or `/` operators, and as such I was wondering what are the downsides of implementing all operator overloading code as non-member functions, so that e.g. I could just placed them all on a separate header file that would only need to be included if there is need for arithmetic functionality. I understand one solution would be to define a new `class myNumericClass : public myClass` that just implements operator overloading, but that would require a new typename and limit the versatility of `myClass`.

Comment: There is no obvious problem with having the operators in another header. It's a good solution IMHO. The inheritance solution is not good.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The primary shortcoming of implementing compound assignment as a non-member is inconsistency with the simple (copy or move) assignment operator. A simple copy or move assignment (i.e., `operator=`) *must* be implemented as a member function, or the compiler will outright reject the code.

Given that copy/move assignment *must* be implemented as member functions, many prefer to implement compound assignment as members as well.

As an aside, this code:

```
template <typename _type, typename _input_type> 
inline myClass<_type> operator+(myClass<_type>& _o1, myClass<_input_type> _o2) { 
    return _o1+=_o2;
};
```

...is, IMO, highly inadvisable. The general style is fine, but you've mixed up which operand to pass by value and which to pass by reference. As a result, it may be needlessly inefficient, *and* (much worse) modifies its left operand, so it really acts like `+=` instead of `+`. What you almost certainly want is more like this:

```
template <typename _type, typename _input_type> 
inline myClass<_type> operator+(myClass<_type> _o1, myClass<_input_type> const &_o2)
{ 
    return _o1+=_o2;
};
```

Here we pass the left operand by value, so when the function is called a temporary value is created and initialized from the left operand. We then modify that temporary value (*without* changing the original) and return it. Since we do return it, there will be copy elision (optional on older compilers, but mandatory since C++17) which means it'll normally really just be a reference to the destination, so effectively, something like: `a = b + c;` will be treated as: `a = b; a += c;`. Since we only need the previous value of the right operand, we pass it as a reference to const to avoid an unnecessary copy (though, depending on the type, passing by reference may not gain enough to care about, or could even be a loss. But it can be a big gain, and is rarely more than a tiny loss).

Comment: I have implemented copy & move assignment operators, just left it out of the example because they did not seem relevant. Also, there was a typo on the code, I was actually passing both arguments as non-const references, but evidently your point still stands and I'll take it into account. Still, wouldn't it be better to pass *both* operands as const references, won't pass any of them by value create an unnecessary intermediary copy?

Comment: @joaocandre if you need to make a copy anyhow then pass by value is fine